# Powershell - Get only the COM port number

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Can anyone advise on how to extract / get the COM value from this Powershell code:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_PnPEntity | where {$_.Name -like "Standard Serial over Bluetooth link*" -AND $_.DeviceID -like "*AB9078566C8A*"} |
>>       Format-Table Name
```

The Output as the moment is:

```
Name
----
Standard Serial over Bluetooth link (COM10)
```

I want to get only:

```
10
```

UPDATE:

Thanks to @js2010 I was able to get the COM port number from PowerShell.
**If someone can Upvote his answer, I would appreciate it**. I don't have enough rep to do that, atm.
The final code is:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_PnPEntity | 
  where {$_.Name -like 'Standard Serial over Bluetooth link*' -AND 
  $_.DeviceID -like '*AB9078566C8A*'} | 
  % name | select-string \d+ | % { $_.matches.value }
```

Comment: You might also be interested in `Get-PnpDevice`.

Comment: I get the result that I need with 
<code> Get-WMIObject Win32_PnPEntity </code> 
But I need somehow to filter to get the value 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?  `%` is a shortcut for `foreach-object`.  `\d+` is regex for numbers.  Matches is an object property output by select-string, and value is a property inside matches.

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_PnPEntity | 
  where {$_.Name -like 'Standard Serial over Bluetooth link*' -AND 
  $_.DeviceID -like '*AB9078566C8A*'} | 
  % name | select-string \d+ | % { $_.matches.value }

10
```

I tested it like this:

```
[pscustomobject]@{name='Standard Serial over Bluetooth link (COM10)'} |
  % name | select-string \d+ | % { $_.matches.value }

10
```

Comment: I like the idea, but the problem is that `select-string`  is a whole table. And I only need to filter the `Name` entry of the table and then get the number from that string.

Comment: genius. Thanks!! 
Now all I need is to figure out how to get the result to a VS variable.

Comment: Get number from (), it does not work on well know device:
Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART Bridge (COM91)

Comment: try select-string -Pattern '(?<=COM)\d+'

Answer (score 0):

Use regex.

```
$a = "Standard Serial over Bluetooth link (COM10)"
$a -match '\d+'
$matches[0]
10
```

Comment: it doesn't work, for some reason, I get 5

Comment: The value of `a` in my case is a whole table. I was able to make it work like this: 

```Get-WMIObject Win32_PnPEntity | where {$_.Name -like "Standard Serial over Bluetooth link*" -AND $_.DeviceID -like "*AB9078566C8A*"} | Format-Table Name```
`$a = Format-Table Name`
`$a -match '\d+'`
`$matches[0]` 

But I am trying to make it shorter

 @navylover

Comment: Once you put it into format-table, it's unusable.